# Drag the cutom control in a scene builder

Tags: javafx

I faced the problem of not pulling nodes after I inherited from Class Pane, I don't know why this problem happened. Please find a solution to my problem

```
package assist.design.roots;
import javafx.beans.DefaultProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

@DefaultProperty("children")
public class AdvancedPane extends Pane {
    public AdvancedPane() {
        super();
    }

    public AdvancedPane(Node... children) {
        super(children);
        getChildren().addAll(children);
    }

    public AdvancedPane(Node... children) {
        super(children);
        getChildren().addAll(children);
    }

    @Override 
    public ObservableList<Node> getChildren() {
        return super.getChildren();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Get rid of your AdvancedPane and just use a Pane or a Pane subclass suitable for your layout.  Your AdvancedPane doesn't do anything a Pane doesn't do.  The method overrides which call the super methods only don't do anything which the super methods don't already do.  And the statements which add child nodes are redundant as the super call already does that.  You are trying to add the nodes twice, which isn't allowed, so it will just remove the existing ones and add the new ones instead (which are the same as the existing ones).

Comment: Can you put a full example here please